# How to specify onChange type of antd select component

Tags: typescript, next.js, antd

I have a question while using next.js, typescript, and antd in my current project.

Although the following types are specified in the onchage function of the antd select component, the following errors occur in the value and onchage functions.

I've been trying to solve the problem, but I can't seem to find a way.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Select } from 'antd';

const Home = () => {
  const [postCount, setPostCount] = useState<number>(10);

  const postCountOptions = [
    {
      value: 5,
      label: 'Count 5',
    },
    {
      value: 10,
      label: 'Count 10',
    },    
  ];

  const onChangeCount = useCallback((value: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setPostCount(value);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>  
     <Select
        defaultValue={10} 
        onChange={onChangeCount} 
        options={postCountOptions} 
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

This is the first error that occurs.

```
const onChangeCount = useCallback((value: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setPostCount(value); // Error 1.
  }, []);

(parameter) value: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>
Argument of type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<number>'.
  Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>' is not assignable to type '(prevState: number) => number'.
    Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: number): number'.ts(2345)
```

This is the second error that occurs.

```
<Select
        defaultValue={10} 
        onChange={onChangeCount} // Error 2.
        options={postCountOptions} 
      />

(JSX attribute) onChange?: ((value: unknown, option: BaseOptionType | DefaultOptionType | (BaseOptionType | DefaultOptionType)[]) => void) | undefined
Type '(value: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: unknown, option: BaseOptionType | DefaultOptionType | (BaseOptionType | DefaultOptionType)[]) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>'.ts(2322)
Select.d.ts(99, 5): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SelectProps<unknown, BaseOptionType | DefaultOptionType> & { children?: ReactNode; } & { ...; } & { ...; }'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the wrong type on the onChangeCount function.
Use `number` instead of `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>`

So, the code looks like this

```
const onChangeCount = useCallback((value: number ) => {
 setPostCount(value);
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the method you said is the method I tried at first.

The method is generating the following error in the onchange function.

Comment: Type '(value: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: unknown, option: BaseOptionType | DefaultOptionType | (BaseOptionType | DefaultOptionType)[]) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the type with the Select component. Also you do not need to explicitly define the type `number` with useState (unless you have different requirement). Once you pass the intial value to useState, typescript will automatically infer the correct type by checking the intial state value.

```
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { Select } from 'antd';
import { DefaultOptionType } from 'antd/es/select';

const Home = () => {
    const [postCount, setPostCount] = useState(10);

    const postCountOptions = [
        {
            value: 5,
            label: 'Count 5'
        },
        {
            value: 10,
            label: 'Count 10'
        }
    ];

    const onChangeCount = useCallback((value: number, option: DefaultOptionType | DefaultOptionType[]) => {
        setPostCount(value);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <Select<number> defaultValue={10} onChange={onChangeCount} options={postCountOptions} />
        </>
    );
};

export default Home;
```